# Program terminates before Flux would finish when using delayElements

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I'm learning about reactive programming but I have a doubt, I'm trying to execute the following code but I don't understand why if I add delayElements before subscribe the elements are not printed

Without delayElements the values are shown

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.time.Duration;

public class PlayWithFlux {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.just(1, 2, 3);
        flux.log().subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

With delayElements the elements are not shown

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.time.Duration;

public class PlayWithFlux {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Flux<Integer> flux = Flux.just(1, 2, 3).delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
        flux.log().subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Is there an explanation about this behavior ?

Comment: its because the program probably ends before it can emit elements. Subscribe is fire and forget. Place a `Thread.sleep(5000)` on the last row before the program ends

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `delayElements` does as it says, it delays before emitting elements.

Calling `subscribe` is not a blocking event, its an async, or "fire and forget" operator.

So what is actually happening is that you call `subscribe` then the main flow continues and ends the program, before any values have time to get emitted.

To solve this just quick and dirty is to delay the end of the program with for instance a call to `Thread.sleep()`

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Flux.just(1, 2, 3)
        .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
        .subscribe(System.out::println);

    // Delay program shutdown so we can watch the elements get printed
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are only using `Flux.just` and `subscribe`, then everything is executed on the main thread, so the program will terminate only after the `Flux` is finished.

Once `delayElements` steps into the picture, the `Flux` is no longer executed on the main thread. Internally `delayElements` switches to a so-called parallel scheduler, which is basically a thread pool. Since now the `Flux` is running on a different thread, the main thread will continue the execution without waiting for the `Flux` to finish and the program will terminate before the `Flux` would finish.

Instead of using `Thread.sleep`, it is better to use one of the `block...` methods in this case. This way the program can finish right after the `Flux` finished:

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
    Flux.just(1, 2, 3)
        .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
        .doOnNext(System.out::println)
        .blockLast();
}
```